# How to modify footnote placeholder in docx4j

Tags: docx4j, footnotes

I have a docx file which contains a footnote. I have a placeholder in the footnote text that needs to be replaced. While extracting the  nodes and modifying the textvalue that placeholder went unpassed. For some reason I think it is not picking up the text provided in the footnote.

Can u please guide me as to how u get to replace a placeholder in the footnote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @JasonPlutext's answer did not work for my case I am posting what worked for me

```
FootnotesPart fp = template.getMainDocumentPart().getFootnotesPart();
List<Object> texts = fp.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:t", true);

for(Object obj : texts) {
    Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement) obj).getValue();
    String textValue = text.getValue();
    // do variable replacement
    text.setValue(textValue);
}
```

But still I face the issue when exporting this as pdf using Docx4J.toPDF(..);
The output does not pick up the footnote reference.

Comment: What version of docx4j are you using?  Which method of PDF output (FO or the commercial converter)?

Comment: I am using docx4j-3.2.1 and using the method Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, FileOutputStream).
I am not using the commercial convertor.

Comment: May be a limitation in the FO based approach.  You could debug/enhance that, or you could try the commercial converter at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

faster if you haven't yet caused unmarshalling to occur:

```
FootnotesPart fp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFootnotesPart();
fp.variableReplace(mappings);
```

**Approach 2**

```
    FootnotesPart fp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFootnotesPart();

    // unmarshallFromTemplate requires string input
    String xml = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(fp.getJaxbElement(), true);
    // Do it...
    Object obj = XmlUtils.unmarshallFromTemplate(xml, mappings);
    // Inject result into docx
    fp.setJaxbElement((CTFootnotes) obj);
```

Comment: Currently I am using wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart() and then extracting via XPath, the JAXB nodes and changing the values of placeholders by normal String replace. With that approach, I am unable to see the footnote in the output document. There is just "1" written there denoting the index of footnote. My question is can I combine extracting JAXB nodes "<w:t>" from the WordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart() and this footnotes part?

Comment: The footnotes are in the footnotes part.  Of course you can use the index of the one you want to manipulate it...

Comment: Its not happening, I tried approach 1. Should I show u the output file? I can post it somewhere